# Ensuring the Security of Publicly Available Libraries

Tags: python, security, shared-libraries

I was looking for a solution to make my python scripts standalone.  To this question, a stack overflow user recommended [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-can-i-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependen) library.

My question is, how can I be sure that the library is secure and not provided by a bad actor?  If I will be using this to provide tools for customers, how can I be sure there's nothing in there that's malicious?

Are there places developers review code and comment on them?

Comment: This question is more about development practices than code itself; I would've suggested asking this elsewhere but [someone already has](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/163522). Does that answer your question?

Comment: @RandomDavis that post focuses more on abandoned libraries than security.  Would you recommend I ask my question on that site/forum?

Comment: I want to be careful about recommending anything, but if you feel that some site is a better fit than StackOverflow (according to its guidelines), then you could try posting there (while making sure you meet all their guidelines).